# Prevent new activity instance after clicking on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, instance, notifications

application (non-wanted) behavior -

1. application is started, some text is put into text-box and notification is created through button action.
2. user "clicks" the home button, application is "minimized", notification is available in bar
3. user selects the notification and the application is "maximized"

BUT - instead of the original instance, new instance is started (e.g. in the newest instance is missing the original text; when the latest instance is closed there is still the original instance with original text ) .

the code of the notification method

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "someText1";
    CharSequence contentText = "someText2";
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notifyIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RadioStream.class);
    PendingIntent intent = 
       PendingIntent.getActivity(RadioStream.this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);

    notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

i have also in the manifest xml file following tag

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

but it is still the same...
The main problem is double/triple initialization of the application, i know that there are other means to preserve the values in resumed applications.
Also it is needed that the applications stays running in background as the main functionality is the streaming of internet radio.

What is missing in the code ? 
What kind of information from my side is missing for to troubleshoot the issue ?

Thanks!

Dav

Comment: so have u found any solution for this dude ??? coz i have same prob as u faced please reply

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047683/android-how-to-resume-an-app-from-a-notification/4048069#4048069

Answer (score 24):

What you refer as "application" is most probably an Activity. To avoid re-crating it when bringing up to front, use

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

To have some code running background, you need to realize it as [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: didn't help :-/

re service - understood, i'm abandoning my current activity concept

thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` on your `Intent`.

Comment: I'll be posting code later today on `http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials` (look at `20-Notifications`) that demonstrates this technique.

Comment: This does the trick if you also have set android:launchMode="singleTop" for the given activity in the manifest.

Comment: I added Warpzit's comment to CommonsWare's solution, it's working for me. Thanks.

Comment: Think this @CommonsWare answer should be right answer. In addtiona I found that only using the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag worked for me. Including the  `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` too caused blank screen momentarily prior to Activity starting....not quite as slick.

Answer (score 4):

add this flag to your activity properties.

> android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 2):

You can set PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT on the PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

If the activity already exists,The new one will cancel and not update the old one!
This works for me!

Answer (score 1):

reimplemented as service - everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

This will bring the app back to its *MainActivity* even if it has opened child activities. Child activities are also cleared.

AndroidManifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Code:

```
val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used GCM example as base code for a personal project and I faced the same issue described on top.
GCM Example: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play

I found a solution by combining to answers:

1) From @ognian answer, by adding to App Manifest on application section:

**android:launchMode="singleTop"**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    **android:launchMode="singleInstance">**
```

2) From @CommonsWare by setting **setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)**

```
private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me by using below combination.

1) add launch mode in Manifest file 
**android:launchMode="singleInstance"**

2) set setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) while creating intent.

intent = new Intent(this, StartUpActivity.class);
    **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);**

Answer (score -2):

instead of :

```
notifyIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), RadioStream.class);
PendingIntent intent =   PendingIntent.getActivity(RadioStream.this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
```

simply use these lines,it will helps you,

```
notifyIntent = new Intent();
PendingIntent intent= PendingIntent.getActivity(RadioStream.this, 0, notifyIntent, 0);
```