# Android Notification restarts app but want to resume

Tags: android, background, notifications, foreground, android-pendingintent

Hi I have a been able to get a notification displayed for my activity, and when the user 
    clicks the notification the app restarts. However I just want it to reappear not restart. eg. it is a web app and I want it to come to the front when the user selects the notification..but not refresh the web page. Can I trap this intent or am I sending the wrong intent? Normally if I press the home button and click on the app icon the app comes to the fore and doesn't refresh/restart. So this is the behaviour I want. Any ideas ?

```
 String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                                             getSystemService(ns);
 //2.Instantiate the Notification
 int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
 CharSequence tickerText = "My App";  // temp msg on status line 
 long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
 //3.Define the Notification's expanded message and Intent: 
 Context context = getApplicationContext();
 CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification";
 CharSequence contentText = "My app!"; // message to user
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HelloAndroid2.class);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
                                                          notificationIntent, 0);
 notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                                                          contentIntent);
 //4.Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:  
 final int NOTIFICATION_ICON_ID = 1;
 mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ICON_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I put this in manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This fixed the problem for me. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4048069/447356) which I have not tried which allude to other things of interest.

Answer (score 13):

If you have to avoid setting your activity to "singleInstance", then set the notification's intent as follows:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT (the document describes exactly what you want to)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HelloAndroid2.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering I put this in manifest, fixed the problem for me android:launchMode="singleInstance" also these answers allude to other things of interest.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047683/android-how-to-resume-an-app-from-a-notification and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047683/android-how-to-resume-an-app-from-a-notification

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution working for me here :

```
    //Resume or restart the app (same as the launcher click)
    val resultIntent = Intent(context, MyLauncherActivity::class.java)
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)  //builder is the notificationBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to set the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP for this particular situation, if you use android:launchMode="singleInstance" it would affect the behaviour when you call other intents in your application, example using facebook sdk, paypal sdk etc..

The explanation is simple right here:
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is already listed as an answer - thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from manifest from .MainActivity activity portion if you have it there:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

This is fatal for not being able to resume app on Samsung devices (and others) with Android newer then 7

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the above with no success (App kept restarting) until I removed:

`intent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());`

which I'd recently added to see if I could fix notification issues with Android 14.  Now I'm using:

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)`

to return to a timer that's running, and it is happily still running as desired.