# Android webview Notification from Javascript

Tags: android, notifications

How can I make the showToast inside the JavaScriptInteface call the CreateNotification?

Here is my code:

CheckInventoryActivity.java

```
package com.CheckInventory;;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class CheckInventory;Activity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    String username; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myimage);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.124/android");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }

    public void OnResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume();
         CancelNotification();
    }


    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nodata.html");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public void CreateNotification()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notifying", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;              // icon from resources
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
        CharSequence tickerText = "Chess";              // ticker-text
        CharSequence contentTitle = "CheckInventory;";      // message title
        CharSequence contentText = "You have an action to take";      // message text

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(CheckInventory;Activity.this, CheckInventory;Activity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(CheckInventory;Activity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;    
        mNotificationManager.notify(1234, notification);
    }

    public void CancelNotification()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lets get it on!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(1234);
    }
}
```

JavaScriptInterface.java

```
package com.CheckInventory;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm new at working with Java and Android, at when I try to call the method, it gives me an error because it is not static. Bottom line I am looking for the JavaScriptInterface to create a Notification.

Since I am this new, I would need a sample code that has direct relation to my problem.

Your help is appreciated!!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that `CheckInventory;Activity` is not a valid class name, the rest seems to be alright. If notifying the user **has** to be done in your Activity, this is one approach.
In your `JavaScriptInterface`'s `showToast()` call `CreateNotification` as so:

```
((CheckInventoryActivity)mContext).CreateNotification();
```

This casts your `mContext` variable so it is a `CheckInventoryActivity` then calls your `CreateNotification` method.

If `mContext` is not *always* an instance of `CheckInventoryActivity` then you will need to do something like this:

```
 if (mContext instanceof CheckInventoryActivity){
      ((CheckInventoryActivity)mContext).CreateNotification();
    }
```

However, I don't understand why you don't put your notification code directly in `JavaScriptInterface`. You have a `Context` variable (`mContext`), and the Notification & Intents require a `Context` variable as one of the arguments. Simply put, you seem to have the necessary tools to display a Notification right from that Non-Activity Class. Just make sure to call `getSystemService(ns);` as `context.getSystemService(ns);` and to remove all the `getApplicationContext()` method calls.

Comment: A--C: Great answer thank you!  I was able to do this with the ((CheckInventoryActivity)mContext).CreateNotification();  I am just curious as to why when I click on the notification, it shows as if the app is re-starting and not just showing the page as it was left.

Comment: The Activity's `onCreate()` method is called again. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605207/android-notification-restarts-app-but-want-to-resume) may be of help if you want to change this behaviour.

Comment: A--C How do I change this behavior?

Comment: @MrM as the link says, you may want to look at adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the manifest. Unfortunately I can't be of much help as I haven't used these flags.

Comment: I tried the singleinstance, but the behavior stayed the same.  I will continue working thru this.  Sincerely, Thank you for your help.