# Push Notification does not launch the background app first time Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, push-notification, mobile-application, background-application

First to begin, there are already answered threads for this question. I have tried everything mentioned in

[Android Notification restarts app but want to resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605207/android-notification-restarts-app-but-want-to-resume)

[Resume application and stack from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)

[Notification to restore a task rather than a specific activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity)

[Open application after clicking on Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716723/open-application-after-clicking-on-notification?newreg=ccb1d02301614d929126e75338c6c1a6)

to mention a few.

My problem, when my android app is in background and i click on a notification, the app does not launch (i am using Unity), the app launches and it shows a blank screen. In the logs I see Unity is getting invoked and these are pretty much the last logs from unity

I/Unity ( 1196): onPause 
D/Unity ( 1196): Releasing Unity-ProjectRequestedWakeLock 
D/Unity ( 1196): Sensor : Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.153229 / 0.01s ; BMA2x2 3-axis Accelerometer / Bosch

And i will have to close to app. From the next time, when the app is in background, on clicking on notification, the app launches. The logs are pretty much the same. I have used all the combination of Intent flags, mentioned above in the links, along with the changes to Manifest.xml.

Let me know if i am missing out something.

Comment: Did you wrote your code in onResume function ?

Comment: I have used the default code pushwoosh gave, and it looks something like this
 void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
 {
  //make sure everything runs smoothly even if pushwoosh is not initialized yet
  if (pushwoosh == null)
   InitPushwoosh();
  
  if(paused)
  {
   pushwoosh.Call("onPause");
  }
  else
  {
   pushwoosh.Call("onResume");
  }
 }