# Activity not closing after being started my Notification

Tags: android

I am experiencing a weird behavior on my android application. When I open my application, I see my DashboardActivity, then I hit home button or back button and my application closes. This is ok. Then I receive a push message and with this push message I create a notification. The notification works fine, I click the notification and it opens my activity, using the code below:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BookingOfferActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("booking", booking);
notificationIntent.putExtras(b);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Then I execute some task in this BookingOfferActivity activity and call the method finish() to make sure this activity will be finished no matter what. Then I open my application again, but instead of seeing the DashboardActivity I am still seeing BookingOfferActivity.

I have tried the solution proposed here:

[Prevent new activity instance after clicking on notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111362/prevent-new-activity-instance-after-clicking-on-notification)

but it just doesnt work.

Is there a way to force my application to always open on the DashboardActivity?

Thanks

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange behaviour considering you are calling finish()

Try setting

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in the manifest for the BookingOfferActivity

Comment: Hi @triggs, I just this what you said, it didnt work. After calling finish() on my BookingOfferActivity and opening my application again, the activity is still there. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: very strange, perhaps you should edit your question with some code from your BookingOfferActivity, also try removing CLEAR_TOP from the notificationIntent

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly, but u can try to finish all activities in onStop() method.
in onResume() method start your DashboardActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing SINGLE_TOP from your intent. CLEAR_TOP should be all you want.

From the Android Developer documentation

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** -> If set, the activity will not be launched if
>   it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: Hi Lionel, still not working with your answer. I am still trying to figure out why this is happening. Thanks again